# How to get value member of checked items in checkedlistbox windows control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

am using the following code to bind a `checkedlistbox` in win form.I want to get the value member of of checked items in checkedlistbox ?

```
listCollection = new List<ListItem>();
            listCollection.Add(new ListItem { text = "Manufacturer", value = "1" });
            listCollection.Add(new ListItem { text = "Dealer", value = "2" });
            listCollection.Add(new ListItem { text = "Distributor", value = "3" });
            listCollection.Add(new ListItem { text = "Trader", value = "4" });
            listCollection.Add(new ListItem { text = "Service Provider", value = "5" });
            chkListCategory.DataSource = listCollection;
            chkListCategory.DisplayMember = "text";
            chkListCategory.ValueMember = "value";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what is `ListItem` but I suppose it is a class that is looks like:

```
public class ListItem
{
    public string Text;
    public object Value;

    public ListItem(string text, object value)
    { /*...*/ }
}
```

So, change the `DisplayMember = "text";` to `"Text"` and `ValueMember = "value";` to `"Value"`:

```
chkListCategory.DisplayMember = "Text";//"text"; 
chkListCategory.ValueMember = "Value";//"value";
```

The display text at UI will be "Manufacturer, Dealer, Distributor, ..."

And the values will be "1, 2, 3, ..."

**Get the value member of checked items:**

To get the values of checked items:

```
//first checked item.
var value = (chkListCategory.CheckedItems[0] as ListItem).Value;

//all checked items.
foreach (var value in chkListCategory.CheckedItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine((value as ListItem).Value);
}

//value at any index in the chkListCategory:
var value = (chkListCategory.Item[index] as ListItem).Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

Bind CheckedListBOx or any other control with displaymember and valuemember is quite simple you just need to specify  datasource property of control as well as displaymember and valuemember.

```
Following is working code 100 % work for me i have tested:

/* checkedlistbox bindig code */

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

string strChechboxlist = "select Subject_ID as code, SubjectName as Display from dbo.Mst_Subject_Detail";

/* filldataset() is function i have created to return dataset. */
ds = dc.FillDataSet(strChechboxlist);
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
checkedListBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "Display";
checkedListBox1.ValueMember = "code"; 

}

/* for fetching valuemember or displaymember from checkedlistbox */


for(int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
{

/*Now with the following code we can get valemember and displaymember as per your requirement you can store in table. */
DataRow r;
r = ((DataRowView)this.checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[i]).Row;
string val = (r[this.checkedListBox1.ValueMember]).ToString();
string dis = (r[this.checkedListBox1.DisplayMember]).ToString();
r = null;

}
```

Note :- I am attaching working demo of code

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to **get some records from Database and put these in a CheckedListBox**

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT Code, GenericName FROM tbl_Item", Connection);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        chklItems.DataSource = null; // chklItems is a CheckedListBox
        if (chklItems.Items.Count > 0)
            chklItems.Items.Clear();
        chklItems.DataSource = dt;
        chklItems.DisplayMember = "GenericName";
        chklItems.ValueMember = "Code";
```

**To Get value member of checked items**

```
for (int i = 0; i < chklItems.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
        {
            string code = ((DataRowView)chklItems.CheckedItems[i]).Row["Code"].ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
foreach(DataRowView view in chkListCategory.CheckedItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(view[chkListCategory.ValueMember].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Can not convert `ListItem` to `DataRowView`.